# Inverting Amplifier Not Giving Gain of -2.2

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, resistors

A [LM358N op amp](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM258.pdf) is used with `R_f = 220k` and `R_i = 100k`, which should give a gain of `-2.2` in a inverting amplifier. It is powered by a regulated +5V supply.

[image]

However while the input voltage is `1.000V` as read by a multimeter, the output is `0.032V`. Why is the gain ~1 and the output not inverted?

[image]

Comment: It's not negative because there's nothing for it to go negative *with*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs a negative rail. Without that it can't go below ground. Also the LM358 isn't really rail to rail. It can work near ground, but not at it, and it needs about 1.5V from the positive supply.

Comment: Looks like I should use a rail-to-rail opamp like `MCP6002-I/P` and `LMC662CN/NOPB` and use it as a non-inverting amplifier? I only have +5V and GND to power the opamp.

Comment: Rail to rail opamps are best especially if you only have 5V to work with. Still won't go negative though. You'll need to have a virtual ground reference or shift everything to be between 5V and zero.

Comment: LMC662 looks like a compatible but better choice than the LM358.

Comment: MCP6002 at $0.40/pc is quite a bit cheaper than LMC662 at $1.64/pc. If MCP6002's slower slew rate is sufficient for my 60Hz signals, seems like I should go with MCP6002.

Comment: Gain bandwidth of the MCP6002 isn't much lower than the LMC662. Shouldn't matter. And if your app can use non-inverting then you may not need a negative rail.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Gsills, there is no negative power rail for it to go negative. The LM358 is a pretty old, and for general purposes where you would 'expect' rail-to-rail ( 0V -> VCC) outputs it doesn't cut it.

Your comment of using an MCP6002 is a good idea, it will definitely get the job done. Just make sure it's slew rate and in general it's bandwidth ratings can do the frequency of expected signals you need. If you are doing things mostly at DC then it's fine.

If you expect the output to increase with the input, then use non-inverting arrangement. If you want your output to go towards 0V as the input increases (negative feedback) then you would want the inverting arrangement.

to give it a negative supply, try a simple 7905 series linear regulator. http://www.jaycar.com.au/images_uploaded/LM7905.PDF

Also do not forget to place local supply supply decoupling capacitors for supply rails, as fast changes in the opamp output will sag/not behave correctly if there is a lack of available current/energy storage nearby.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish this circuit to function with only a single 5V supply available you are going to have create a negative rail somehow. A DC-DC converter or a 7660 charge pump will do it. Some use a MAX232 to generate +/-9V with the help of a few capacitors.